# .htaccess rewrite to redirect all root URLs to a new subdirectory EXCEPT one specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, root, subdirectory

My WP site has two languages. Default language (EN) used to be the default language, and the 2nd language (NL) in a subdirectory. Now all pages and directories in the default language have also been moved to a subdirectory, and the root url just shows a splah page where you are forced to choose your language.

So all stuff in `root.com/...` should be redirected with a 301 redirection rule to `root.com/en/...`

*Except* all stuff in `root.com/nl/...` which should just stay in `root.com/nl/...`

**AND** *Except* the splash page with the language selection which remains `root.com`

How should I write the redirection rules in the htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite simple actually.

We use a RewriteCond to check that the requested URL path did not start with `/nl/`. The `^` anchors the pattern at the start of the test string, and the `!` negates it.

And in the RewriteRule pattern, we demand that the path consists of at least one character. The leading `/` has already been stripped off at this point (only when the rewriting is configured in .htaccess though, if it was done via the central server configuration, that would be different) - which means, the request for your splash screen at the root URL will be an “empty” path here. By anchoring the pattern at the start and finisch, and using the `+` quantifier, we demand that the path must consist of at least one character here, so this rule will simply do nothing, if the root path was requested.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nl/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /en/$1 [R=302,L]
```